# How to prevent Intellisense to show fields without "this" prefix in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I'm using StyleCop to ensure that I only access fields with the `this.` prefix. This works like a charm but I'm wondering if there is an option for intellisense to hide suggestions for fields when I'm not explicitly prefixing the current expression with `this.` like it does for `TypeScript` class fields.

Thanks!

Comment: hmm ... really nothing?

Comment: ok, final countdown - it seems like I'm the only one in the world that would find such a thing useful :-)

Comment: If you change your style so that you name your fields with a leading underscore, you won't need to bother with `this.` anymore at all, and Intellisense should make it a little more clear distinguishing between local variables and fields. I don't think there's an official C# standard, but I've seen the underscore convention more often than not in the places I've worked.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I actually like the `this.` convention because it's pretty obvious what it means to an outsider that doesn't know of the convention being used (`_blubb`, `m_blubb`, `blubb_` etc.) plus it is in line with access to static members - you always see exactly what is being called at a glance as opposed to e.g. having to hover the code. I know it's a matter of taste but I saw that VS has this behavior in TypeScript so I wondered whether this is a *feature* of the TypeScript compiler or something every IntelliSense implementation has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing this now, there seems to be no switch for IntelliSense to achieve this.